# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I using Jquery data tables to show data to the user of my application. My data is coming from Server using Ajax. This is what I am doing

```
$('#order-table').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": TippNett.Api.Url + "Order/DataTable",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.token = authToken;
        }
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "OrderType", render: getOrderTypeImg },
        { "data": "Location" },
        { "data": "MassType" },
        { "data": "Amount" },
        { "data": "RemainingAmount" },
        { "data": "CreatedDate" },
        { "data": "StartDate" },
        { "data": "EndDate" },
        { "data": "Org" }
    ]
});
```

It looks fine and everything is working. But the issue is that when I am trying to search I have two cases where it fails

- If I copy the item to be searched and paste it in the search box I get no result and in the console I get the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.tippnett.com/Order/DataTable?draw=18&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=Or…yggv&search%5Bregex%5D=false&token=8587465804588061807sn6n&_=1455024583582. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.tippnett.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

- The second case is more weird. So lets say my table has locations with different locations. One of them is Norway. When I type Norw it shows me the results but if I keep on typing ahead it gives me the same above error.

My server code is this

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
[AdminAttribute]
public dynamic DataTable([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
    {
        int totalRecords = Order.GetAll().Count();

        IEnumerable<Order> list;
        if (requestModel.Search.Value != null && requestModel.Search.Value != "")
        {
            String searchValue = requestModel.Search.Value.ToLower();
            list = (from a in Order.GetAll().OrderByDescending(i => i.To)
                    where
                    a.Amount.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    (a.Amount - a.MatchedAmount).ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.GetOrganization().Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.GetLocation().FriendlyName.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.GetMassType().Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.From.ToShortDateString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.GetCreatedDate().ToShortDateString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    a.To.ToShortDateString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue)
                    select a);
        }
        else
            list = Order.GetAll().OrderByDescending(i => i.To);


        int filteredRecords = list.Count();

        DataTables.Mvc.Column orderColumn = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns().FirstOrDefault();

        if (orderColumn != null)
        {
            Func<Order, String> keySelector;

            switch (orderColumn.Data)
            {
                default:
                case "MassType":
                    keySelector = r => r.GetMassType().Name;
                    break;
                case "Location":
                    keySelector = r => r.GetLocation().FriendlyName;
                    break;
                case "Org":
                    keySelector = r => r.GetOrganization().Name;
                    break;
                case "StartDate":
                    keySelector = r => r.From.ToShortDateString();
                    break;
                case "EndDate":
                    keySelector = r => r.To.ToShortDateString();
                    break;
                case "CreatedDate":
                    keySelector = r => r.GetCreatedDate().ToShortDateString();
                    break;
                case "Amount":
                    keySelector = r => r.Amount.ToString();
                    break;
                case "RemainingAmount":
                    keySelector = r => (r.Amount - r.MatchedAmount).ToString();
                    break;
            }

            if (orderColumn.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant)
                list = list.OrderBy(keySelector);
            else
                list = list.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }

        list = list.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length).ToList();

        List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (Order order in list)
        {
            Location loc = order.GetLocation();
            Organization org = order.GetOrganization();


            data.Add(new
            {
                DT_RowId = order.Id,
                Location = loc.FriendlyName,
                MassType = order.GetMassType().Name,
                Amount = order.Amount,
                RemainingAmount = order.Amount - order.MatchedAmount,
                CreatedDate = order.GetCreatedDate().ToShortDateString(),
                StartDate = order.From.ToShortDateString(),
                EndDate = order.To.ToShortDateString(),
                Org = org.Name,
                OrderType = order.OrderType.ToString()

            });
        }

        return new
        {
            draw = requestModel.Draw,
            recordsTotal = totalRecords,
            recordsFiltered = filteredRecords,
            data = data
        };
    }
```

Here is how I am handling the CORS

public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

```
    public override bool Match(object obj)
    {
        return base.Match(obj);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Method.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));

                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you see this '[AllowCrossSiteJson]' I have handled CORS. And it is the same api which gives me result. The issues I get are when there is no result found. Then I get this error.

Comment: I didn't, no, but then it's also not a standard ASP.Net thing. Clearly it's failing to do its job in some situations. So that's where to look, the implementation of that attribute.

Comment: I added the definition for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was having was because that I was getting data using GET instead I had to use POST because of the limitations we get on GET request.